# Android ListView with Subtext

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm a beginner, and my first android app I'm creating is supposed to keep track of strikes for different people.

I want to have their name and then underneath that, a subtext that shows how many strikes they have. I'm not sure how to go about this.

Here's what I have so far:

```
private void populateListView() {
    String[] myItems = {"Alex", "Laura", "John", "Tom"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter=new
            ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            myItems);

    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.people);
    list.setAdapter(myAdapter);
}
```

Also, when an item on the list is pressed, it uses toast to display their position and name:

```
private void registerClickCallback() {
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.people);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> paret, View viewClicked, int position, long id) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) viewClicked;
            String message = "You clicked" + position + "which is string" + textView.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(Hello.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

How do I create the subtext that shows how many strikes a person has and how do I make it so that when it is pressed, it increases by one?

Comment: as @El_Mochiq written, instead of `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`, use `layout_list_item` as he wrote. Then inside `onItemClick`, write:  TextView textView1 = (TextView) viewClicked.findViewById(R.id.txt_name); TextView textView2 = (TextView) viewClicked.findViewById(R.id.txt_num_strikes); Then Toast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do a custom adapter with a custom layout for each item of the list you are showing so each item would be something like this:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_list_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/name"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_num_strikes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="normal" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

and then inflate that view into the cutsom adapter,
check this: http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/android/android-custom-listview-example/

EDIT:

Create a class:

```
public class Person
{
 private String name;
 private int strikes;

public Person(){}

public Person( String _name, int _strikes)
{
  this.name = _name;
  this.strikes = _strikes;
}

public String getName()
{
  return name;
}

public int getStrikes()
{
  return strikes;
}

public void setName (String Name)
{
 this.name = name;
}

public void setStrikes (int strikes)
{
 this.strikes = strikes;
}
}
```

Create a Custom adapter:

```
public class ListPeopleAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;

    protected List<Person> listPeople;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ListCarsAdapter(Context context, List<Person> listPeople) {
        this.listPeople= listPeople;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return listPeople.size();
    }

    public Person getItem(int position) {
        return listPeople.get(position);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_list_item,
                    parent, false);

            holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
            holder.txtStrikes = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txt_num_strikes);


            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Person person = listPeople.get(position);
        holder.txtName.setText(person.getName());
        holder.txtStrikes.setText(""+person.getStrikes()); //using ("" +) instead of .toString()

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtName;
        TextView txtStrikes;
    }

}
```

And on your activity:

```
    private void populateListView() {

ArrayList<Person> arrayPeople = new ArrayList<Person>();

Person person1 = new Person("Alex", 1);
Person person2 = new Person("Laura", 3);
Person person3 = new Person("John", 2);
Person person4 = new Person("Tom", 5);

arrayPeople.add(person1);
arrayPeople.add(person2);
arrayPeople.add(person3);
arrayPeople.add(person4);

// Get the ListView by Id and instantiate the adapter with
        // cars data and then set it the ListView
        ListView listV = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.people);
        ListPeopleAdapter adapter = new ListPeopleAdapter(context, arrayPeople);
        listV .setAdapter(adapter);


}
```

PS: I am coding directly here so any syntax error could appear.

Comment: why wouldn't we setTag(person)?